# Mysql update field in table based on another field's condition in same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with key/value columns. I need to update a key/value pair based on another value's condition.

Table:

```
--------------------------
| id | key     | value   |
--------------------------
| 1  | country | canada  |
| 2  | privacy | default |
--------------------------
```

In this case I need to change `value` to `canada` where `key = privacy` only IF `country = canada`.

I've tried something like this:

```
UPDATE settings
SET value =
    CASE
        WHEN key = 'country' AND value = 'canada' THEN 'canada'
        ELSE value
    END
WHERE key = 'privacy'
```

but it results in an error on the `CASE` condition. I think I might need to do some sort of sub-query?

Comment: can you share the settings table for reference.

Comment: IF(value = 'canada') THEN
    UPDATE settings
    SET value = 'canada'
    WHERE key = 'privacy'
    END IF;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement won't work as you can't have a record with both a key of 'privacy' and 'country'. You need to perform a SELECT on the table itself to check if 'country' is set to 'canada'. Something like the following may work.

```
UPDATE settings
SET value = 'canada'
WHERE key = 'privacy'
  AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM settings WHERE key = 'country' AND value = 'canada') AS temp_settings);
```

Comment: except I believe it's better practice to use AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM settings WHERE key = 'country' AND value = 'canada');

Comment: You're right. For some reason I forgot EXISTS existed.

Comment: I'm getting `Error : You can't specify target table 'settings' for update in FROM clause`.

Comment: My Mistake. In MySQL you can't update the same table you're performing a select on, unless the table is temporary. I've updated the solution, as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)